How Digitally Sign a .pdf document using usb token(Watchdata Proxkey) in ubuntu 22.04
I am trying to digitally sign a pdf document using usb token(Watchdata Proxkey).How can i do this in ubuntu 22.04? is there is any FOSS software for this purpose?

Does this answer your question? Putting Digital Signature on PDF in Ubuntu 20.04
